# URL Masking in Angular 12

Tags: angular, url, masking

In Angular URLs, users can easily see the controller's name and the routing path.

```
Ex: localhost:4200/Product/Category
```

How can a URL can I hide that and get a dynamic URL like

```
localhost:4200/AOaemvL0iJkx0Gsb7aMGy7oEP013WAeLog%3A1636097188967
```